# C# ¿Saber la posición de un entero?

Tags: c#, algoritmos

Vale, la idea del problema es sencillo, dado un entero, multiplicar cada elemento con el siguiente, el problema es que no tengo la menor idea de como identificar la posición de cada digito en el entero, sin hacer uso de dividir entre 10, 100, 1000 etc...

Por lo que intenté pasarlo a string, una vez pasado en string tomar el elemento `[0] , [1] , [2]` etc, volver a pasar el char que se genera en string (ya que si no al convertirlo de nuevo al entero me devuelve la representación es ASCII), y por ultimo convertirlo en entero.

De la siguiente forma:

```
  for(int it = 0; it <= number.ToString().Length; it++){
      another *= Convert.ToInt32((number.ToString()[it]).ToString());
     }
```

El problema de esto, es que por alguna razón, si tengo un entero digamos 39, y hago un return de esto como modo de prueba.

```
return Convert.ToInt32((number.ToString()[0]).ToString());
```

En lugar de obtener 3 obtengo 4, y no sé de dónde sale ese cuatro.

Igualmente, si no convierto el char generado a string, es decir dejandolo así.

```
return Convert.ToInt32((number.ToString()[0]);
```

Obtendría 51, la cuál como podemos ver es su representación en ascii al pasar un char a entero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Ahora bien, de dónde sale ese dichoso 4? ¿Qué opciones tengo para el problema presentado?

---

Edito:

```
using System;

public class Persist 
{
    public static int Persistence(long n) 
    {

   int counter = 0;
   int number = Convert.ToInt32(n);
   int another = 1;

   while(number > 9){

     for(int it = 0; it <= number.ToString().Length; it++){
      another *= Convert.ToInt32((number.ToString()[it]).ToString());
     }

     number = another;
     another = 1;
     counter++;

   }
    return counter;
    }
}
```

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? (Advierto de que es un reto de codewars, asique no estoy tan segura de que tan lícito sería obtener la respuesta, preferiria una pequeña ayuda, pues realmente no sé que es lo que está pasando...)

Comment: Probé con esta línea y sí funcionó, mostró "3" en la consola `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(("39".ToString()[0]).ToString()));`, ¿estás seguro que el número está bien?

Comment: Pues, es posible que el numero cambiase dado que son random tests (es de los retos de codewars), he editado el tema, pues ahora estoy pensando que es posible que haya algo mal con mi código.

Comment: La excepción se debe a que estás usando `<=` en la comparación del `for`, debería ser solo `<` porque sino se va a pasar por 1 y tratará de acceder una posición del array que no existe

Comment: Te prometo que estaba convencida que eso ya lo había intentado, (e incluso llegue a hacerlo restandole -1 al total del length) y nada de eso daba resultado. Es más, en mi cabeza lo habia hecho mentalmente y estaba super convencida que con `<` hacia una iteracion más. Acabo de editarlo de nuevo y compilarlo, y ahora funciona...

Comment: Vale, antes no funcionaba porque olvidé volver a poner la variable another a 1, por eso al quitar el `=` aunque la iteracion estaba bien, me devolvía error, de ahí que me estuviese volviendo loca. Muchas gracias @DiegoTorres

Answer (score 1):

¿Entiendo bien que quieres producir el producto de los dígitos de un número?

Si es así, puedes convertir el número a un string, seleccionar cada carácter del string, convertirlo a int, ajustar el valor obtenido (porque, como has visto, `'0'` se convierte en 48 etc.) y hacer la multiplicación. Utilizando LINQ es muy fácil:

```
int producto = numero.ToString()
                     .Select(c => (int)c - 48)
                     .Aggregate(1, (r, d) => r * d);
```

**EDIT:** Una solución más tradicional podría ser así:

```
int producto = 1;
foreach (char c in numero.ToString())
    producto *= (int)c - 48;
```

Answer (score 1):

aquí te dejo dos opciones en un mismo programa sin convertir a string, usando solo int.

La primer solución multiplica los dígitos de derecha a izquierda, como el orden de los factores no altera el producto obtienes el mismo resultado.

En segundo lugar te dejo una solución quizás un poco más elegante que multiplica de izquierda a derecha utilizando recursividad. Espero te sirva.

```
using System;
namespace Multiplicar
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Opción 1 si no importa el orden.
            int num = 1234;
            int res = 1;
            while (num > 10)
            {
                res *= num % 10;
                num = num / 10;
            }
            res *= num;
            Console.WriteLine(res);

            // Opción 2 respetando el orden y con recursividad.
            Console.WriteLine(MultiplicarDigitos(1234));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static int MultiplicarDigitos(int num)
        {
            if (num <= 9) return num;
            return MultiplicarDigitos(num / 10) * (num % 10);
        }
    }
}
```

En ambos casos la salida será 24.

Comment: Perdón, el operador del while debió ser mayor igual, así: while (num >= 10)